# Mantine UI Grid - first column on first row that only spans x spaces

Tags: reactjs, mantine

I'm trying to use Mantine UI grid to create a form layout.

The layout I'm trying to achieve is a single column on the first row that only spans 4 grid spaces. See simple diagram below:

XXXX

XXXX XXXX XXXX

I've tried using offset:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Col xs={12} md={4}>Row 1 Column 1</Grid.Col>
    <Grid.Col xs={12} md={4} offsetMd={8}>Row 2 Column 1</Grid.Col>
</Grid>
```

However this offsets it on the second row by 8 grid sizes.

The only way I've gotten this to work is by using another grid item, and wrapping it in a media query:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Col xs={12} md={4}>Row 1 Column 1</Grid.Col>
    <MediaQuery smallerThan="md" styles={{ display: "none" }}>
        <Grid.Col md={8}></Grid.Col>
    </MediaQuery>
    <Grid.Col xs={12} md={4} offsetMd={8}>Row 2 Column 1</Grid.Col>
</Grid>
```

But this is kind of ugly. Just wondering if I'm missing something and there is a better way to achieve this.